# Good Patterns for integrating modern Java systems with file systems

Tags: file, filesystems, jms, integration, apache-camel

We have a system that is going to send our system a lot of file deliveries.

We would prefer to not build a layer on top of the files system that polls and triggers the corresponding process for that file, since a file system gives no benefits such as transactions, isolations, etc.

We are thinking of using Apache Camel to watch for the files, and then send a message to a queue to signal its arrival. Since we are dealing with a message queue, we will get all the benefits that come with that, such as transparency over the message queues, sending acknowledgement back when successful, etc.

Does this sound like a good thing to do, or are there better patterns with dealing with file systems?

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to route and pass around files to different servers, route them etc. then your approach is probably good. You need to think twice though.

A message transaction can be rolled back, but files can't. Also you really need to think about all cases you want to solve - draw all possibilities in sequence diagrams to make sure your solution won't be too complex and that all error cases are handled.

Perhaps, a solution where Camel picks up the files and routes them on is good enough? Then you can implement logging etc. But it won't be transcational.

ActiveMQ has something for situations like this, called [BLOB messages](http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html) which aims to enable large file transfer in out of band channels, but using the JMS messages for control "signals". It might or might not suit your case, depending on your specific requirements.